# Python IDLE on Windows 11

Tags: python, windows, python-idle

I upgraded to Windows 11 recently. I have both 3.7 and 3.8.6 installed. In windows 10 the edit with had 2 options - 3.7 IDLE and 3.8.6 IDLE since I need both versions.

Now I only get the 3.7 IDLE option. I suspect I need to edit the registry but am not willing to do this.

A workaround is to add IDLE 3.8.6 to the open with menu but this is not as convenient.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I would like to have both options in the menu for edit with IDLE as I had with WIN 10. Also I am not sure why the 3.7 IDLE is the edit option and not the 3.8.6 IDLE

Comment: I did manage to edit the registry and have solved this issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming, and because the OP provided the answer in the question.

Comment: You might report this on bugs.python.org.  New OS versions tend to have little changes with un-anticipated effects.

Comment: yes, close the question _ I solved my problem